# h5py open file with unknown datasets

Tags: python, hdf5

I try to use h5py to open a file which was created by another program. Unfortunately I don't know the inner structure of the file. All I know is that it should contain a 20x20 matrix which I would like to process with numpy.
Here is what I have done so far:

```
import numpy
import h5py
f = h5py.File('example.hdf5')
print(f.keys())
```

The result is as follows:
    `KeysViewWithLock(<HDF5 file "example.hdf5" (mode r+)>)`

How do I go from here? I want to access the matrix as a single numpy.ndarray. The h5py documentation always talks about creating hdf5 files, not reading unknown files.
Thanks a lot.

SOLUTION (thanks to akash karothiya)
use `print(list(f.keys()))` instead. That gives the names of groups/datasets which can then be accessed as `a=f['dataset']`.

Comment: `list(for.keys())`

Comment: Thanks, now I can know how the dataset is named and get some data with a = f['dataset']. Converting to numpyarray should be easy, no help needed for that (I hope).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, as mentioned before akash karothiya helped me find the solution.
Instead of `print(f.keys())` use `print(list(f.keys()))`. This returns `['dataset']`.
Using this information I can get an h5py dataset object which I then converted into a numpy array as follows:

```
a = f['dataset']
b = numpy.zeros(np.shape(a), dtype=complex)
for i in range(numpy.size(a,0)):
    b[i,:] = np.asarray(a[i]['real'] + 1j*a[i]['imag'], dtype=complex)
```

**UPDATE**:
New version without for loop, potentially faster and very versatile (works for both complex and real data and cubes with dimensions NxMxO as well):

```
a = f['dataset']
if len(a.dtype) == 0:       
    b = np.squeeze(a[()])          
elif len(a.dtype) == 2:       
    b = np.squeeze(a[()]['real'] + 1.0j*a[()]['imag'])
```

Comment: If your dataset was a 2xN array, you could do `X, Y = f["dataset"].T` `Z = X + 1j*Y`.

Comment: That's a nice solution. I have actually moved on to the version just posted, as there I do not need to think about dimensionality or real/complex any more.